# How can I embed the Power BI in my Spring based project?

Tags: java, spring-boot, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

How can i embed the Power BI on my spring Boot application.
I have been looking for it for too long now,but nothing helps.

If anyone had came across the same, Please let me know .

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few scenarios to consider for embedding. Here are some common ones:

**For use within your organisation**.

I.e. the people viewing the embedded reports will be from the same domain as the publisher. For this you can use the secure embed option in the PowerBI portal. Once your report is published to the PowerBI service, you can get a link to use - see below. You would use the link provided in an iframe on a web page.  Users will need a PowerBI Pro license to access the reports and dashboards. You can find [more info on this option here](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/easily-embed-secure-power-bi-reports-in-your-internal-portals-or-websites/).

[image: Get PowerBI embed link]

**For any anonymous user**

You can use the Publish to web feature (you can see it on the menu options in the image above). This allows you to publish your report for anyone on the internet to view. You can [find more info here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-publish-to-web). Do be careful of the limitations of this option.

*Limitations*

- Reports using row level security.
- Reports using any Live Connection data source, including Analysis Services Tabular hosted on-premises, Analysis Services Multidimensional, and Azure Analysis Services.
- Reports shared to you directly or through an organizational content pack.
- Reports in a group in which you are not an edit member.
- "R" Visuals are not currently supported in Publish to web reports.
- Exporting Data from visuals in a report, which has been published to the web.
- ArcGIS Maps for Power BI visuals.
- Reports containing report-level DAX measures.
- Single sign-on data query models.
- Secure confidential or proprietary information.
- Shared and certified datasets.
- The automatic authentication capability provided with the Embed option doesn't work with the Power BI JavaScript API. For the Power BI JavaScript API, use the user owns data approach to embedding.
  For B2C applications where your users are from a different domain - or anonymous. This requires using the separate PowerBI embedded SKU.

**Embedding with "User Owns Data"**

This approach is typically used for independent software vendor (ISV) type applications where the app owns access to the data. Users aren't necessarily Power BI users, and the application controls user authentication and access.

You can [find more info here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embed-sample-for-your-organization)

**Embedding with PowerBI embedded Azure Capacity**

An alternative to the above is to use the PowerBI embedded capacity in Azure which allows you the highest level of control, including scaling capacity. You can [find more info here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/azure-pbie-what-is-power-bi-embedded).

Comment: Thanks for your answer , This really helps ...
Can you also elaborate on how can I design reports, by getting the data from MYSQL DB(As this is the one we are using for our Application) .

Comment: PowerBI has a built in connector for mysql - the docs are pretty good, start here https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/desktop/